Что делать если Asset в Unity 2D изменил работу некоторых компонентов?
я хотел взять свет у Ассета который я скачал, но когда я его импортировал этот ассет добавил новые слои, удалил некоторые теги, изменил работу Gravity Scale в Physics 2D и Material у которого шейдер расположен по пути Sprites/Diffuse (то-есть когда у объекта в компоненте Sprite Renderer стоит этот материал тогда если Sprite Renderer/FlipX = false то он становиться прозрачным, тоже самое будет если у объекта в Transform/Scale = -0.1 и <). Из-за этого игра сломалась (ну технически она работает только не так как надо) и я хочу откатить свои действия либо как-то по другому исправить проблему.Как я могу это сделать?
если нужно то игра на версии юнити 2020.3.26f1 (64-bit).
